# Spiral spring/coil viewed from an angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would one create this coil that is viewed from an angle/distorted perspective?

[image: coil-side-view]

Closest i got:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.5]

\draw[line width = 1pt, scale = 1.3]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,20}
        {
            (0,0) circle (\i pt)
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed. If you need a pointer, start by reading a tutorial for TikZ, and then edit your question to focus on a specific problem that you have when trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Your picture looks like a perspective to me, so this is a solution using `perspective` library (form Ti*k*Z), and `isometric view`, for example.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]
\draw plot [domain=0:7200,samples=2000] ({\x/360*cos(\x)},{\x/360*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Purely for comparison, you can do that in a [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) "one-liner".

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
draw (origin for i=1 upto 129: .. (i, 0) rotated 45i endfor) yscaled 1/2;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex` to get this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could you start with something like this and improve on it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [rotate=-45]
              plot[domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75]  ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t} and {0.004*\t*\t} );
    \end{tikzpicture}

       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [rotate=45]
             plot[domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75] ({\t  r}: {0.002*\t*\t} and {0.004*\t*\t} );
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]